# DevExpress MVC PivotGrid Custom Actions Keep Firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I am using a DevExpress MVC Pivot Grid and trying to work out some problems with the loading and saving of layouts. So far I have the following:

I have set my **CustomActionRouteValues** in the **PivotGridSettings** as follows:

```
CustomActionRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "PivotGridCustomCallback" },
```

Which points to the following:

```
public ActionResult PivotGridCustomCallback(string action, string reportName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reportName))
    {
        reportName = "Report 1";
    }

    var settings = PivotGridLayoutHelper.DefaultPivotGridSettings;
    if (action == "Save")
    {
        // TODO: Find a better solution than this. At the moment, if Save is called once, it is then called again every time the user changes the layout.. which is why we have the 'saved' variable here.
        bool saved = false;
        settings.AfterPerformCallback = (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (saved)
            {
                return;
            }
            SaveLayout(((MVCxPivotGrid)sender).SaveLayoutToString(), reportName);
            saved = true;
        };
    }
    else if (action == "Load")
    {
        // TODO: Find a better solution than this. At the moment, if Load is called once, it is then called again every time the user changes the layout.. which is why we have the 'loaded' variable here.
        bool loaded = false;
        string layoutString = LoadLayout(reportName);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(layoutString))
        {
            settings.BeforeGetCallbackResult = (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (loaded)
                {
                    return;
                }
                ((MVCxPivotGrid)sender).LoadLayoutFromString(layoutString, PivotGridWebOptionsLayout.DefaultLayout);
                loaded = true;
            };
        }
    }

    ViewBag.PivotSettings = settings;
    return PartialView("PivotPartial");
}
```

The problem, as you can see in the code comments, is that after performing an action just one time, it then gets called EVERY time I make any sort of change. So, for example... say I load a report.. that's fine.. but then when I try expand something or add a field.. or do ANYTHING, nothing seems to happen on the UI.. and I figured out that's because immediately, this code gets called again:

```
settings.BeforeGetCallbackResult = (sender, e) =>
                {
                    ((MVCxPivotGrid)sender).LoadLayoutFromString(layoutString, PivotGridWebOptionsLayout.DefaultLayout);
                };
```

That just keeps resetting the values to the saved layout, which means the UI looks like it's unresponsive when trying to change anything.
This is why I now have the boolean variable called **loaded** to check if it's already loaded. That works.. but it's an ugly hack.. because it's making unnecessary trips to the server each and every time the user does anything on the pivot grid.

Surely there must be a way to prevent these actions from firing all the time?